# Why someone send this transaction

Tags: transactions

I've just received strange transaction from unknown address: transaction hash is `6e41f6acb7541cf4ffeddf126dbd87a01092be8d021a897350a6a332ba67a071`, the sender sent `0.0215 BTC` to about 3000 outputs (`0.00000546 BTC` to each), where one of the output was mine, full transaction is about `95 KB` of size. I used the address (which is on of the output) only for private use and didn't share it explicitly.

What can be the purpose of such transaction? Does this sender is trying to spy on all receivers, or what it can be?